# What is the meaning of "despise" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "despise" in this sentence :

> The more one closes themselves off to a changing career, the more they
>   come to despise that field

I have tried to Google it but still not understand it.

Hope someone could explain for me. Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: What did the OP find on Google? Does the OP understand what "despise" means? Did the OP look the word up in a dictionary? Where does this excerpt come from: a book, a website? We don't know because Tan Nguyen did not tell us. It's anyone guess to know why the OP is confused.

Answer (score 1):

> **despise**
>
> feel contempt or a deep repugnance for.

It's difficult to say without the full context, but I imagine it means that if one is working in a field where there is an expectation to change and grow in alignment with changes in the field itself (for example, new technologies or working practices), the more one will begin to feel contempt towards that field (e.g., one might feel excluded or left behind and begin to blame the field of work itself for doing this to them).

As an example: A person is working as a computer programmer. They begin to realise that the programming languages they are an expert in are becoming out of date, and that they'll need to learn new ones to keep up with progress in the industry (and continue to secure work). This upsets them, and they begin to despise the field of computer programming - "Why are they always bringing out new languages? There's nothing wrong with the ones I'm using! This industry is ridiculous!"

Comment: I'm sorry but can you give me more example. It will be helpful for me to understand what you try to explain for me :(

Comment: I've added an example - let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ohhhhh, it's a lot of help, I can imagine it not only by words but by movie scene (it reminds me Joey in Friends by the way)

Once again thank you ^_^